# In fortran how to read all strings line by line from a .dat file in fortran

Tags: fortran, fortran90, fortran95

I have a .dat file , from which I am trying to read line by line and print it.
Can anyone please help about how to do it in fortran?

Thanks in advance!

Data:

```
REMARK    GENERATED BY TRJCONV
TITLE     UNNAMED t=   0.00000
REMARK    THIS IS A SIMULATION BOX
CRYST1   26.178   26.178   26.178  90.00  90.00  90.00 P 1           1
MODEL        1
ATOM      1  S2  LJ2     1      17.000  15.030  11.630  1.00  0.00            
ATOM      2  S2  LJ2     2      13.290  11.340  15.900  1.00  0.00            
ATOM      3  S2  LJ2     3      17.030  23.070  14.750  1.00  0.00            
ATOM      4  S2  LJ2     4      15.360  14.840   9.480  1.00  0.00            
ATOM      5  S2  LJ2     5      15.780   4.560   9.580  1.00  0.00            
ATOM      6  S2  LJ2     6       5.350  22.490  11.110  1.00  0.00            
ATOM      7  S2  LJ2     7      19.940   3.910  10.840  1.00  0.00            
ATOM      8  S2  LJ2     8      20.380  13.360  15.680  1.00  0.00            
ATOM      9  S2  LJ2     9      18.340   4.200   7.720  1.00  0.00            
ATOM     10  S2  LJ2    10      18.610  16.530   9.910  1.00  0.00            
TER
ENDMDL
```

Code:

```
program atom_test

implicit none

 character (LEN=75) ::inputdatafile,outputfile
 real,dimension(100) :: x, y
 integer :: i,n,nframes
character (len=200),dimension(3000):: command

 print *,"Give the datafile name:"
 read *,inputdatafile
outputfile=inputdatafile(1:len(trim(inputdatafile))-4)//"_output.dat"
!write(*,*)outputfile
Open(9, file=inputdatafile, status='old')

call linesFile(inputdatafile,n)
write(*,*)n

do i=1,n
  read(*,*),command(i)
  write (*,*)command(i)

end do
close(9)

end program atom_test
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!! find the number of lines in a file
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
subroutine  linesFile(fileIn,n)
implicit none
 Character(len = 50)   :: fileIn
integer, intent(out) :: n
! locals
integer :: iostatus, unit_read
real    :: dummy


unit_read = 9
open(unit=unit_read, file=fileIn)

n =0
DO
  READ(unit_read, *, IOSTAT=iostatus) dummy
  IF (iostatus < 0) EXIT
    n = n + 1
END DO

 ! WRITE(*, '(i8, a, a)') n, ' bins read from file: ', fileIn
 close(unit_read)

end subroutine  linesFile
```

Given marked answer works fine. As I am very new in Fortran I have one more question related this. I want to get the elements separately from the ATOM rows in my data file
for example:
ATOM      1  S2  LJ2     1      17.000  15.030  11.630  1.00  0.00

```
from here i want to store 1,s2,LJ2,1,17.000,15.030 each in different parameters. In that case I am using this
```

/* With the code marked as correct

```
    ncount=0
 do i = 1, n

       IF (command(i)(1:4).eq.'ATOM') THEN
         ncount=ncount+1
         read(read_unit,*) p, p2, p3,p4,xatom(ncount)
         write(*,*),p

       endif
end do
```

But it is not working.Can you please give me one suggestion about how to read individually from those lines which starts with ATOM?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are a few things I notice straight away:

1. The line `read(*, *) command(i)` reads the first element of standard input, not from the file. I think you want to `read(9, *)`.
2. Actually, you'll probably want to `read(9, '(A)')` because you want to read the whole line, not just until the first element separator (i.e. space or comma).
3. In your subroutine, you open the file again, under the same unit. That is... dangerous if not wrong. Better to just read from the file, then use the `rewind` command to move the read position back to the beginning of the file.

   ```
   program atom_test

       implicit none
       integer :: ios
       integer, parameter :: read_unit = 99
       character(len=200), allocatable :: command(:)
       character(len=200) :: line
       integer :: n, i

       open(unit=read_unit, file='data.dat', iostat=ios)
       if ( ios /= 0 ) stop "Error opening file data.dat"

       n = 0

       do
           read(read_unit, '(A)', iostat=ios) line
           if (ios /= 0) exit
           n = n + 1
       end do

       print*, "File contains ", n, "commands"

       allocate(command(n))

       rewind(read_unit)

       do i = 1, n
           read(read_unit, '(A)') command(i)
       end do

       close(read_unit)

       do i = 1, n
           print*, command(i)
       end do

   end program atom_test
   ```
4. If you already dedicate 3000 lines in the beginning, there's no real reason to read everything twice:

   ```
   program atom_test

       implicit none
       integer :: ios
       integer, parameter :: read_unit = 99
       character(len=200) :: command(3000)
       integer :: n, i

       open(unit=read_unit, file='data.dat', iostat=ios)
       if ( ios /= 0 ) stop "Error opening file data.dat"

       n = 0

       do
           read(read_unit, '(A)', iostat=ios) command(n+1)
           if (ios /= 0) exit
           n = n + 1
       end do

       print*, "File contains ", n, "commands"

       close(read_unit)

       do i = 1, n
           print*, command(i)
       end do

   end program atom_test
   ```
5. In your subroutine to read the number of lines in the file, you try to read a `REAL` from a file where the first word is often not a number. This might lead to `IOSTAT` being non-zero, even if you haven't reached the end of the file. Always read a `character` variable.

Comment: Hi , Thanks a lot . That works fine. As I am very new in Fortran I have one more question related this. I want to get the elements separately from the ATOM rows in my data file

Answer (score 3):

This post provides an answer to OP comment:

> I want to get the elements separately from the ATOM rows in my data file

Assuming `input.txt` looks like:

```
ATOM  1   S2  LJ2  1   17.000  15.030  11.630  1.00  0.00                       
ATOM  2   S2  LJ2  2   13.290  11.340  15.900  1.00  0.00                       
ATOM  3   S2  LJ2  3   17.030  23.070  14.750  1.00  0.00                       
ATOM  4   S2  LJ2  4   15.360  14.840  9.480   1.00  0.00                       
ATOM  5   S2  LJ2  5   15.780  4.560   9.580   1.00  0.00                       
ATOM  6   S2  LJ2  6   5.350   22.490  11.110  1.00  0.00                       
ATOM  7   S2  LJ2  7   19.940  3.910   10.840  1.00  0.00                       
ATOM  8   S2  LJ2  8   20.380  13.360  15.680  1.00  0.00                       
ATOM  9   S2  LJ2  9   18.340  4.200   7.720   1.00  0.00                       
ATOM  10  S2  LJ2  10  18.610  16.530  9.910   1.00  0.00
```

You could

1. read columns into strings
2. read real numbers from strings
3. output the results

```
      program fort                                                              
      integer n, i                                                              
      parameter (n=10)                                                          
      real r1(n), r2(n), r3(n), r4(n), r5(n), r6(n), r7(n)                      
      character(len=255) format, s1(n), s2(n), s3(n), s4(n), s5(n),             
     &                           s6(n), s7(n), s8(n), s9(n), s10(n)             
      i=1                                                                       
      open(unit=99, file='input.txt')                                           
2     read(99,3,end=1) s1(i), s2(i), s3(i), s4(i), s5(i),                       
     &                 s6(i), s7(i), s8(i), s9(i), s10(i)                       
      i=i+1                                                                     
      goto 2                                                                    
3     format(a6,2a4,a5,a4,3a8,a6,a4)                                            
4     format(a6,f4.1,2x,2a4,f4.1,5f8.3)                                         
1     close(99)                                                                 
      read(s2,*) r1                                                             
      read(s5,*) r2                                                             
      read(s6,*) r3                                                             
      read(s7,*) r4                                                             
      read(s8,*) r5                                                             
      read(s9,*) r6                                                             
      read(s10,*) r7                                                            
      do i=1,n                                                                  
         write(*,4) s1(i), r1(i), s3(i), s4(i), r2(i),                          
     &              r3(i), r4(i), r5(i), r6(i), r7(i)                           
      enddo                                                                     
      end
```

output:

```
ATOM   1.0  S2  LJ2  1.0  17.000  15.030  11.630   1.000   0.000
ATOM   2.0  S2  LJ2  2.0  13.290  11.340  15.900   1.000   0.000
ATOM   3.0  S2  LJ2  3.0  17.030  23.070  14.750   1.000   0.000
ATOM   4.0  S2  LJ2  4.0  15.360  14.840   9.480   1.000   0.000
ATOM   5.0  S2  LJ2  5.0  15.780   4.560   9.580   1.000   0.000
ATOM   6.0  S2  LJ2  6.0   5.350  22.490  11.110   1.000   0.000
ATOM   7.0  S2  LJ2  7.0  19.940   3.910  10.840   1.000   0.000
ATOM   8.0  S2  LJ2  8.0  20.380  13.360  15.680   1.000   0.000
ATOM   9.0  S2  LJ2  9.0  18.340   4.200   7.720   1.000   0.000
ATOM  10.0  S2  LJ2 10.0  18.610  16.530   9.910   1.000   0.000
```

---

A better approach consists on

1. read columns into variables (strings, integers, or reals)
2. output the results

```
      program fort                                                              
      integer n, i                                                              
      parameter (n=10)                                                          
      integer i1(n), i2(n)                                                      
      real r1(n), r2(n), r3(n), r4(n), r5(n)                                    
      character(len=255) format, s1(n), s2(n), s3(n), s4(n), s5(n),             
     &                           s6(n), s7(n), s8(n), s9(n), s10(n)             
      i=1                                                                       
      open(unit=99, file='input.txt')                                           
2     read(99,3,end=1) s1(i), i1(i), s3(i), s4(i), i2(i),                       
     &                 r1(i), r2(i), r3(i), r4(i), r5(i)                        
      i=i+1                                                                     
      goto 2                                                                    
3     format(a6,i4,a4,a5,i4,3f8.3,2f6.2)                                        
4     format(a6,i4,2x,2a4,i4,5f8.3)                                             
1     close(99)                                                                 
      do i=1,n                                                                  
         write(*,4) s1(i), i1(i), s3(i), s4(i), i2(i),                          
     &              r1(i), r2(i), r3(i), r4(i), r5(i)                           
      enddo                                                                     
      end
```